# I have a JSON that I want to use in my Unity C# application where some properties are overloaded

Tags: c#, json

Here's a simplified example.  I want to pull in JSON data where the following are options:

```
{
  "cost": 5
}
```

or

```
{
  "cost": { "base": 5, "inc": 2}
}
```

Right now I'm using `JsonUtility.FromJson<MyObject>` which forces me to choose a single type.  I am willing to convert one format to the other, so `{"cost": 5}` can become:

```
class MyObject
{
  MyEntry cost = new MyEntry { @base = 5 };
}
```

Is there a way to do this using `JsonUtility` or another parser?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know or can't guarantee your object layout, then you'll have to use the dynamic mode.

```
var parsed = JObject.Parse(jsonString)
```

From here, you can call Value to try and get your data out.

```
var data = json.Value<string>("data")
// or
var data = json.Value<MyEntry>("data")
```

That should get you started.

Comment: Is this referring to the JObject from https://www.newtonsoft.com/ ?  Is there a way to do it without that framework, or is that recommended?

Comment: Ah, yeah it is. I don't recall seeing the ability to do 'dynamic' json with the inbuilt one.